# How to use Stokes' theorem without knowing the curl of the vector field?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vector-analysis, surface-integrals, stokes-theorem

[image]

For the first part, to find $\alpha$ and $ \beta$, I said that the vector field has to be divergion-less so $\text{div}(\mathbf{F})=0$. So I got $\alpha=-\frac{1}{2},\beta=-3$. However, for the second part, I am not sure how to apply Stokes' theorem, how do I find a vector field $\mathbf{G}$ such that $\mathbf{F}=\nabla \times \mathbf{G}$ to reduce the integral to a line integral??

Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Why not just do the surface integral?

Comment: How would I do it when S can be any surface?

Comment: If the integral is the same no matter which surface you pick, then you can pick an easy one. In this case, I'd say the part of the plane $ z=0$ inside the top half of the unit circle in the xy plane

Comment: Ahaa, i see, so once that I have shown that div(F)=0, then the surface chosen doesn't matter and i can choose a convenient one with an easy normal vector correct?

Comment: You got it. Any surface with that particular boundary will work.